# How to change Query to contain data from joined table?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have simple Entity:

```
id
username
guard
```

"guard" is id of another user from the same Entity. I have to render view with simple table:

```
username | name of guard
-------------------------
John     | Bob
```

I tried to do that by query:

```
$ur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin(User::class, 'u2', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'u.guard = u2.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

but it gives me just id and username, no joined data.
I know that entire query should be like:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  user u0_ 
  LEFT JOIN user u1_ ON (u0_.guard = u1_.id)
```

but I can't find the way to implement that by QueryBuilder and then to access that in twig template.

Regards

Comment: try `->addSelect('u2')`

Comment: Thanks. It returns now Array with User Objects and nulls. I see in profiler that query is good, if I test it in phpMyAdmin I get perfect result. But in Symfony results are different, not correct.

Comment: ->leftJoin('u.guard', 'u2')

Comment: [Semantical Error] I tried in two versions:

    (((1)))   
$ur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)
   ->createQueryBuilder('u')
   ->addSelect('u2')
   ->leftJoin('u.guard', 'u2')

   (((2))) 
$ur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)
   ->createQueryBuilder('u')
   ->addSelect('u2')
   ->leftJoin(User::class, 'u2', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'u.guard = u2.id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out the mistakes in my code:

1. I tried to set that OneToOne realtion and that was small mistake, but I needed here ManyToOne.

```
    /**
     * Many Users have One Guard (User)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $guard = 0;
```

2. When I did that Symfony automatically force me to change my code and in column "guard" I have to insert User object.
3. After that I don't need join anymore - just select data from table and guard column includes User object which I can use in Twig, etc.

```
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
        public function findAllDB()
        {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
            $query = $qb->getQuery();
            return $query->execute();
        }
    }
```